# How to unpublish all nodes of a user after is assigned a role?

Tags: rules, views

I am interested on this scenario:
After a user is assigned a role,all his published nodes get unpublished.
I am interested in doing this with rules and VBO.
I tried but no luck.
I used :Event:User profile is update
Action:Load all node with VBO. 
Seems I am missing something.Anyone help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do this with VBO .
Here is a video which helped me.
http://drupalize.me/videos/using-vbo-load-list-objects-rules
I hope it helps someone else.
THanks!

Comment: I will have to check that out. I haven't used VBO with rules yet. And obviously as we've seen, Views Rules can't solve the problem every time :). Thanks

Comment: The secret is to add the Unpublish action inside the loop so as to have the token available.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead create a Views Loop using the [Views Rules](https://drupal.org/project/views_rules) module. You can create a view and have the rule loop through all the rows that the view outputs.

Edit:

> For Example, I want to send an e-mail to all user's attached to a node
>   registration. So I needed to do the following:
>
> 1. Create a view with a Rules Display. Field: User E-mail. Contextual Filter: NID (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csci1.jpg).
> 2. In the Views Rule Settings - Parameters: I specified the parameter's label and name, that wil need to match the Views Loop Data
>      selector (Step 4) for the Views Contextual filter. (Screenshot:
>      https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLZKn.jpg)
> 3. In the Views Rule Settings - Row Variables: I specified which field should be enabled for Rules, and how it should be passed back to
>      Rules. (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9FhM.jpg)
> 4. I then created a Views Loop in my Rule matching the Parameters and Row Variables in my view (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewUfS.jpg)
> 5. I then created the action "Send mail" under the Views loop using the now available token that was specified in the View. (Screenshot:
>      https://i.stack.imgur.com/NObZJ.jpg)

And that's it. If you want to test your output rather than your unpublish action. I would recommend using the action "Show a message on the site".

In your case your contextual filter is most likely your UID and NID as your field. I used my example as a proof of concept.

Edit 2:

Exported View:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'waiting_list_user_list';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Waiting List User list';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: User: Registration */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration']['id'] = 'registration';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration']['field'] = 'registration';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration']['label'] = 'User Registration';
/* Relationship: Registration: Registration to Node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration_related_node']['id'] = 'registration_related_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration_related_node']['table'] = 'registration';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration_related_node']['field'] = 'registration_related_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['registration_related_node']['relationship'] = 'registration';
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['alter']['strip_tags'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['relationship'] = 'registration_related_node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Registration: State entity */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['id'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['table'] = 'registration';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['field'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['relationship'] = 'registration';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['value'] = array(
  'waitlist' => 'waitlist',
);

/* Display: Rules */
$handler = $view->new_display('views_rules', 'Rules', 'views_rules_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['rules_parameter'] = array(
  'nid' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'type' => 'integer',
    'label' => 'nid',
    'name' => 'nid',
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['rules_variables'] = array(
  'mail' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 0,
    'type' => 'token',
    'label' => 'User: E-mail',
    'name' => 'mail',
  ),
);
```

Exported Rule

```
{ "rules_waiting_list_e_mail_after_registration_deletion" : {
    "LABEL" : "Waiting List E-mail after Registration Deletion",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_i18n", "registration" ],
    "ON" : { "registration_delete" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "registration:state:name" ], "value" : "complete" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "node", "id" : [ "registration:entity-id" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "node_id" : "node_id" } }
        }
      },
      { "VIEW LOOP" : {
          "VIEW" : "waiting_list_user_list",
          "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
          "USING" : { "nid" : [ "node-id:nid" ] },
          "ROW VARIABLES" : { "mail" : { "mail" : "User: E-mail" } },
          "DO" : [
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : [ "mail" ],
                "subject" : "test",
                "message" : "Test",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer,one question:After adding the View loop and the action "Unpublish content"  ,I am not able to show which content to unpublish.I am asked to select this but I cannot.Any thoughts?

Comment: I mean,how do I pass the nodes from the View Rule to the Action "Unpublish content" ?

Comment: Could you please paste the rule here?

Comment: I edited my original post. I hope this helps!

Comment: I have done exactly what you said,there is only one final issue:When making the action to unpublish the nodes,it is not accepted.I take this message:"Data selector nid for parameter node is invalid."

Comment: Could you please export your view and rule?

Comment: Any luck with my exported view/rule?

Comment: Sadly I was able to reproduce the exact same problem. You however don't have the Row Variables data type as "text token". But even after changing it to that, the token is only available with other actions and for some reason not with "unpublish content". I spent a good hour trying to see if I could find a workaround, but sadly I couldn't.

Comment: Is this possible with VBO?What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the view

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'published_cars_of_a_user';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Published cars of a user';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Author uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'car' => 'car',
);

/* Display: Content pane */
$handler = $view->new_display('panel_pane', 'Content pane', 'panel_pane_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Bulk operations: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'action::node_assign_owner_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_delete_item' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_script_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::flag_node_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_make_sticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_make_unsticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_modify_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'show_all_tokens' => 1,
      'display_values' => array(
        '_all_' => '_all_',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'url' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'action::node_promote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_publish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpromote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_save_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::system_send_email_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_by_keyword_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);

/* Display: Rules */
$handler = $view->new_display('views_rules', 'Rules', 'views_rules_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['rules_parameter'] = array(
  'uid' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'type' => 'integer',
    'label' => 'Content: Author uid',
    'name' => 'uid',
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['rules_variables'] = array(
  'nid' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 0,
    'type' => 'integer',
    'label' => 'Content: Nid',
    'name' => 'nid',
  ),
);
```

And here is the rule

```
{ "rules_unpublish_all_emporos_expired_nodes" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unpublish all emporos expired nodes",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "VIEW LOOP" : {
          "VIEW" : "published_cars_of_a_user",
          "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
          "USING" : { "uid" : [ "account:uid" ] },
          "ROW VARIABLES" : { "nid" : { "nid" : "Content: Nid" } },
          "DO" : []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This Rule appears to be incomplete... it doesn't contain the "unpublish" action you were trying to achieve. I am working on a similar situation... I need to unpublish all nodes by a user when a specific event occurs on the website. I cannot get the Rule to provide the needed data selector. Can you please share the complete Rule code?